# How do I "loop" two functions without re-call in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I will be brief, let's take easy examples. I have these two functions:

```
function first() {
  alert("Function One");
}

function second() {
  alert("Function Two");
}
```

I would like to pass from function `first()` to `second()` **without** doing this:

```
function first() {
  alert("Function One");
  second();
}

function second() {
  alert("Function Two");
  first();
}
```

Because I would create a stack overflow (like `first()` is calling `second()` inside of itself, then `second()` that is in `first()` and is calling `first()` again and so on, creating an endless loop that is unwanted)

How could I simply "pass" from a function to another? Ask if you need more informations.

Thank you all.

Comment: so, you want the two functions to infinitely call each other without overflowing the stack? try `setTimeout(second, 0);`

Comment: You say you want to "pass from `first()` to `second()`" but you never mention needing to pass from `second()` to `first()` even though that's what you've done in the code. Why do you need to call `first` from within `second`, is that another requirement?

Comment: Or do you want to pass from first to second (or from first to second) only **once**? I'm not sure what you are trying to do...

Comment: curious about the use case ...

Answer (score 2):

You can simply call the two functions in a loop:

```
while (true) {
    first();
    second();
}
```

But infinite loops like this aren't good in Javascript, this will lock up the browser. It's not clear what you're really trying to do. This will just avoid the stack overflow from recursion.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```js
function second() {
  alert("Function Two");
}

function first() {
  alert("Function One");
}

setInterval(function() { second(first()); }, 1);
```

Comment: This doesn't help with limiting the stack size. Unless there's some JS magic I'm missing.

Comment: My answer doesn't limit the stack size.

Comment: This doesn't do any recursion. It just calls the two functions periodically. It could also be `first(); second();` inside the callback function.

Comment: There's no reason to pass it as an argument, since neither function takes a parameter nor returns a value.

Comment: @Barmar the OP only wants to execute the functions each other and this is a way of doing that.  I'm passing as an argument just to call the `first`  function just before the `second` function.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to achieve is always calling one after the other if it has not already been called, you could do something like:

```
function first(isChained) {
    alert("Function One");
    if (!isChained) {
        second(true);
    }
}

function second(isChained) {
    alert("Function Two");
    if (!isChained) {
        first(true);
    }
}
```

And then you can still call them on their own like:

```
first()
```

and the `isChained` parameter will default to undefined, which will evaluate to `false`, causing `second()` to be called.